Models of KPU with Ordinals as Urelements (and Their Relation to HOD)
I'm exploring models of Kripke-Platek set theory with urelements ($\mathrm{KPU}$) where the class of ordinals, $\mathsf{On}$, is taken as collection of urelements. I have a few questions related to this topic: 

References: Are there any standard references or papers that discuss
the construction or properties of models of KPU where the class of
ordinals serves as the class of urelements?
Relationship with HOD: How do such models, if any, relate to the
class of Hereditarily Ordinal Definable sets?

 
I came across this work, in which Antos, Barton and Friedman make use of $\mathbb{H}\mathrm{YP}(V)$, the (ideal) least admissible structure containg $V$ as a element. I am interested in similar structures on the class $\mathsf{On}$, but also in models of $\mathrm{KPU}$ over $\mathsf{On}$ that do not 'think' of $\mathsf{On}$ as a set, i.e., that do not contain $\mathsf{On}$ as an element.
I would greatly appreciate any pointers to relevant literature or any explanations that clarify these concepts. Thank you!

Do you want the urelement structure to be On merely as a class  or as the class with its usual ordering?

Hi @AndreasBlass! Possibly with the usual ordering, but if you have any reference to works in which they are considered merely as a class I would be interested in those, too :)

I don't have references. The reason for my question was  just that, as mere classes, On and V are pretty much the same.

Dear @AndreasBlass – sorry to bother, but in the meantime I happened to read a paper by Kentaro Fujimoto in which KP over sets is discussed explicitly and compared to theories of truth over ZF(C). Really interesting stuff!
Have a great day!
Here's a link to the paper: https://research-information.bris.ac.uk/ws/portalfiles/portal/169913356/JSL2018.pdf
